# Classifying above ground LiDAR points in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, lidar, classification, las

I recently used the LAS Dataset toolbar to classify a .lasd file. The process classified the majority of points as unassigned with the rest being ground points. The study area has many tall buildings and tree, which did not receive the appropriate classification.

Is there a way of improving the quality of automatic classifications?

Comment: Automatic classification is usually ground/non-ground. There are tools that have a good guess, consider classifying with LasGround http://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasground/ for level 1 (ground/non-ground) and then level 2 classify using LasClassify http://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasclassify/ (buildings/veg) http://rapidlasso.com/category/lastools/ license agreement depends on the tools but is OK (i think) to try before you buy; it's also quite inexpensive, but prices are rising as the software is becoming more recognized.

Answer (score 1):

The LAS Dataset toolbar in ArcMap does not provide any automated classification solutions. The classification that is available through the Profile viewer was meant solely for the facilitation of supervised classification, where you would make a selection and assign the appropriate class code.

In ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 and ArcGIS Pro 1.2, 3D Analyst provides the Classify LAS Ground tool which can be used to obtain a very good classification of ground points on many types of terrain. The freely available [3D Sample Tools](http://links.esri.com/3dsamples) package also provides tools for classifying ground and building points using a TIN based methodology. If portions of your data lays in areas where the above-ground returns only contain vegetation, you may want to consider running the Classify LAS By Height tool to assign the vegetation codes based on their height from the ground.