# Extracting above ground features from unclassified LAS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, classification, las

What's the best way to vectorize features from LAS?

I have "Classified" LAS files, however they were never processed for classification.
Thus of 181 million points (9 tile sample) about 60% are class 1-Unassigned; 35% are class 2-Ground; and the remaining are Key-Reserved and Noise.

Is there a way to extract features (buildings, powerlines, tree canopy) using these LAS files in ArcGIS?

If this cannot be done in ArcGIS, what programs/software are optimized for such processing?

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132036/classification-of-above-ground-lidar-points-in-arcmap/180317#180317 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49066/can-i-use-lastools-to-classify-point-data/49108#49108

Answer (score 1):

This is a really complex subject, many software or methods can do that. I will only list a few here to get you started.

- [Lastools](http://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasclassify/) has a function lasclassify.
- [Global mapper](https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/products/global-mapper-lidar.php) has a Lidar module.
- [Lidar Analyst](http://www.textronsystems.com/products/geospatial/lidar_analyst) comes as an ArcGIS extensions.

Those are easy to use, where you have few parameters to set and pretty good results. Not all of them do powerlines, but they all do buildings and tree canopy.